# optional parameters on report

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

i have a table that has 10 field in Microsoft Access,
but i want filter on their maximum 5 field
i left 5 checkbox and for any once 1 combobox to select 1 to 5 option to filter, in other words dynamic report on 5 filed.
my code:

```
my New code changes:

Dim p1 As Long
Dim p2 As String
Dim p3 As String
Dim p4 As String
Dim p5 As String
p2 = "*"
p3 = "*"
p4 = "*"
p5 = "*"
p1 = 20500101
If (chbeckbox1 = True) Then p1 = combobox1
If (chbeckbox2 = True) Then p2 = combobox2
If (chbeckbox3 = True) Then p3 = combobox3
If (chbeckbox4 = True) Then p4 = combobox4
If (chbeckbox5 = True) Then p5 = combobox5
strCriteria = "([DateCutting]<=" & p1 & ") And [SystemName]= '" & p2 & "' And [CenterName]='" & p3 & "' And [TypeCutting]='" & p4 & "' And [ReporterName]='" & p5 & "'"
task = "select * from Cutting where (" & strCriteria & ")"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter task
```

define 5 variable and ....
but i got no correct result or syntax error
what is solution???

Comment: Use `combobox1.Value` and so on. Then, declaring `Dim p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 As String` it declares all variables except the one `As Variant`. VBA needs `Dim p1 As String, p2 As String....`. No need to initialize variable in that way. They are `nullString`, `nothing`, `""` initially...

Comment: Try putting `Debug.Print p1` after `If (chbeckbox1 = True) Then p1 = combobox1` line and see what it returns in `Immediate Window` (Ctrl + G in VBE).

Comment: ok but when i select two option it return no any record

Comment: i think star considered as a value . no wilcard

Comment: In such a case, or `strCriteria` is wrongly built, or nothing to be returned with respective conditions...

Comment: I think you may be right when suppose that "*" mai not be considered as wildcard. But you can test that. Use 4 parameters and on the fifth one use wildcard directly and see what is happening...

Comment: on directly got Syntax error

Comment: What are the datatypes of the 5 fields?
Do each of the 5 comboboxes contain a value if the corresponding checkbox is checked?

Comment: Ms Access, Yes it corresponding checkbox is checked

Comment: Are these 5 comboboxes UNBOUND? Controls intended for user input of criteria should be UNBOUND, otherwise changes data in record. Conditionally build criteria string - review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, asterisk (*) is wildcard character in Access. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1

Parameters for date/time field need # character as delimiter. `"([DateCutting]<=#" & p1 & "#) And`

If variable type is not explicitly declared it defaults to Variant. So in your variable declaration only p5 is String type, the other 4 are Variant. Default value for Variant type is empty string.

Your criteria is built such that variables are still referenced in concatenation even if empty (null or empty string). The result can be an invalid criteria string - as in passing an empty string for a date/time field. Even if the criteria works without error, output could be not what is desired.

Instead of passing empty strings, use wildcard (*) with text field parameters and provide an alternate value for date/time field.

Alternatively, conditionally build string so field and its parameter are only used if there is value AND user has selected for it.

Comment: i define CuttingDdate to Long Integer type   you skip on CuttingDdate other 4 parameters considered problem is that in "where" , asterisk (*) considered as a vale NO  WILDCARD , so when in table is * value filter worked correct

Comment: Not really understanding that comment. Asterisk can definitely be used as wildcard in WHERE clause. Did you review the Allen Browne link in my other comment? If DateCutting is not a date value, why is Date in the field name?

Comment: ok my means is that when i got correct result that on table there is * value. for example if i filter to [SystemName] and [CenterName] if user select value of SystemName in combobox and left selecting CenterName , when result is correct that in table filed CenterName  have * value NO ANY VALUE